# Event for a Storyboard repeatedly in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, storyboard

I wrote a storyboard which make a ball (imgBall) running repeatedly on a process bar (imgBar) - with repeat behavior = "forever", but I don't see event which occur when single turn start or end, It only have Completed event (which occur when the whole storyboard finished)

```
<Grid Margin="20,0,0,0">
            <Canvas Canvas.ZIndex="1" >
                <Canvas.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard" Completed="myStoryboard_Completed">
                        <!-- Animate the center point of the ellipse. -->
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="imgBall"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                                     Duration="0:0:2"
                                     From="10" To="350"
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                     ></DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Canvas.Resources>

                <Image Source="/Assets/Image/processball.png" x:Name="imgBall">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="10" TranslateY="2"/>                            
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
            </Canvas>

            <Image Source="/Assets/Image/imgBar.png"/>                
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: There is no such event for Storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove RepeatBehavior="Forever" and repeat your Storyboard from code behind in Completed event Handler using .Begin() method.